# Edit output from SQL query to agrupate values

Tags: python, mysql

First of all, I appreciate your help with my problem. I am currently working in a data base using sql in python. This is my code:

```
from tabulate import tabulate #the output generates a table
sql_query = "SELECT DISTINCT dc.name AS disease_code_name, d.drug_name FROM disease_code dc, drug d, drug_disease dd WHERE dc.code_id=dd.code_id AND dd.drug_id=d.drug_id AND dd.inferred_score=(SELECT MAX(dd.inferred_score));"
cursor.execute(sql_query)
score_table = [['1','2']]
for row in cursor:
    nom = row[0]
    sco = row[1]
    list_d = [nom,sco]
    score_table.append(list_d)
print(tabulate(score_table, headers='firstrow', tablefmt='fancy_grid'))
```

The output that it generates is something similar to this:

```
1       2
apple   fruit
orange  fruit
lemon   fruit
pig     animal
lion    animal
tiger   animal
```

But I want something like this:

```
1      2
fruit  apple, lemon, orange
animal pig, lion, tiger
```

Can you help me please?
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Are you able to share `specific query` with us? Using MySQL `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` inside the query itself may be the fastest and easiest way to do this.

Comment: Okay I edit the question

Comment: Yeah with group by it works, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just using `GROUP BY` you can solve the problem. Thank you to [Wander Nauta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182402/wander-nauta) for his help